# Optaplanner: how to avoid the same shift in two consecutive day?

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

This is my second post.
I'm trying to study the nurse rostering examples.
There is a way to avoid same shift in two consecutive day?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid shifts for the same nurse in two consecutive days? If yes, that would not be the same shift. There would be 2 shifts, assigned to the same nurse, with consecutive dates. You can write a constraint that penalizes it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding same shift type in 2 consecutive days goes like this:your "when" clause should be true when  there are 2 ShiftAssignments of the same  nurse,same shift type with your second ShiftAssignment having ShiftDatedayindex = ShiftDateDayIndex of first Assignment +1;
ShiftAssignment(...$ShiftType1:shiftType,day1:shiftDateDayIndex,...)
ShiftAssignment(...$ShiftType2:shiftType,$ShiftType1==$ShiftType2,day2:shiftDateDayIndex,day2==day1+1...)